# Finding the largest factorial with only three distinct decimal digits

Tags: number-theory, factorial

I want to find the largest factorial whose decimal representation contains only three distinct digits. I am using the following Python code to compute the above, but no results up to 16000!:

```
def check(x):
    s=str(x)
    m=0
    if s.count('0')>0:
        m=m+1
    if s.count('1')>0:
        m=m+1
    if s.count('2')>0:
        m=m+1
    if s.count('3')>0:
        m=m+1
    if s.count('4')>0:
        m=m+1
    if s.count('5')>0:
        m=m+1
    if s.count('6')>0:
        m=m+1
    if s.count('7')>0:
        m=m+1
    if s.count('8')>0:
        m=m+1
    if s.count('9')>0:
        m=m+1
    if m==3:
        return True
    else:
        return False
dp=[1,2]
for i in range(3,99999):
    x=dp[i-2]*i
    if check(x)==True:
        print x
    dp.append(x)
```

Is there a better approach?

Comment: Simply calculating factorial and check number of digits. x=dp[i-2]*i is where factorial is calculated using dynamic programming.

Comment: Presumably "composed of only 3 digits" means the decimal representation contains only 3 of the digits 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.

Comment: Thus $5!$, $6!$ and $7!$ qualify.

Comment: Error in code, modified.

Comment: The tags for this question are not really right if the question is about the code.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly are you calculating? Largest three digit factorial is $6!=720$

Comment: It seems that from $n=42!$ onward all $10$ digits occur (I checked up to $n=10000!$). See also [A137580](https://oeis.org/A137580)

Comment: This might be one of those questions that is simple to ask but very very difficult to answer. The answer appears to be $7!=5040$. But it is conceivable (although I don't believe it) that there _is_ no such largest factorial.

Comment: When `n >= 5`, `n!` must end in a `0`, so, at best, only 2 other distinct digits.  So no need for `if s.count('0')>0:`.  And at least 1 of those 2 digits is even.

Answer (score -1):

Update:

Here is a table of the first $50$ factorials (in base 10 = decimal representation): [link](https://gist.github.com/b7b03a3435a44a1f6810).

Its format is
$$
n: (n!)_{10}, l=\mbox{number of places}, di =\mbox{number of diverse digits} 
$$

As noted by fellow user vuur in the comments, the number of diverse digits of $(n!)_{10}$ is listed in OEIS as [A137580](https://oeis.org/A137580). The related sequence of non pandigital numbers (pandigital number = number with all digits of the base occurring) [A182049](https://oeis.org/A182049) is conjectured to end with entry $n=41$.

Following is an heuristic argument, why it is likely that for larger $n$ the decimal representation $(n!)_{10}$ is pandigital, and thus not tridigital anymore, as searched for in the question, making 7! candidate for the largest tridigital factorial.

For this we need to look at the development of a fixed place $k$ with increasing $n$, e.g. $k = 3$, counting from the end of the string, first index being a zero.

This place is implicitly zero until $n = 7$, where $(n!)_{10}$ got large enough to reach this place and it takes the digit $d_3 = 5$, then changes its values a couple of times until it will stay $0$ for $n \ge 16$.
$$
d_3^{(n)}: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 2, 8, 6, 1, 0, 1, 8, 8, 6, 8, 2, 0, 0, 0, \ldots
$$
All places will sooner or later stay at the digit $0$ because the number of zeroes at the end of $n!$ grows with increasing $n$, as new factors $n$ introduce new factors $2$ and $5$ to the factorial, the number of trailing zeroes of $(n!_{10})$ corresponding to the power $j$ in $5^j$ of the prime factorization of $n!$.

The place $k = 3$ has a run of $r_3 = 13$ variable digits until it gets flooded by the trailing zeroes. As the length of $(n!)_{10}$ seems to grow faster than the number of trailing zeroes, those runs $r_k$ should get longer for places with increasing $k$.

The digits change with increasing $n$ from $d_k^{(n)}$ to $d_k^{(n+1)}$ according to the multiplication with carry algorithm is:
\begin{align}
d_0^{(n+1)} &= (n+1) \cdot d_0^{(n)} \mod 10 \\
d_k^{(n+1)} &= \left((n+1)\cdot d_k^{(n)} + c_k^{(n)}\right) \mod 10 \\
c_0^{(n)} &= 0 \\
c_{k+1}^{(n)} &= \left((n+1) \cdot d_k^{(n)} + c_k^{(n)}\right) 
                 - 10 \cdot d_k^{(n+1)} 
\end{align}
The above recursion scheme is similar to the one used in [linear congruential pseudo random number generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) 
or [MWC generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply-with-carry).

The quality of the random numbers regarding their cycle length (they go into a cycle after length iterations) or the distribution of their generated numbers varies with the choice of the parameters and initial value.

My heuristic argument is, that the digits $d_k^{(n)}$ of $(n!)_{10}$ behave similar like those pseudo random number generators and the longer the $(n!)_{10}$ string gets with increasing $n$, the more of those generators get introduced and start generating until caught by the flood of trailing zeroes. Nonetheless their number increases with increasing $n$ and they vary with parameters and initial values. So they produce all base digits, turning $(n!)_{10}$ pandigital. It would be highly unlikely that all those generators are such synched for a certain $n^*$ that they stick just to $3$ digits out of the $10$ possible.

My guess is that if one would apply the statistical tools of the analysis of pseudorandom number generators to the digits evolution of $(n!)_{10}$ one could show or at least better argue for this argument.

Comment: You just formalised the question. :/

Comment: Exactly. I move it to the comment section. Can't remember if I wanted to exetend it to an answer.

Comment: OK, I have updated it into an argument.